# Ehcache limit port ranges

Tags: range, port, ehcache

From the Ehcache documentation, https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.6.9/net/sf/ehcache/distribution/RMICacheManagerPeerListener.html

The cache peer listener have parameters as
**port - a port in the range 1025 - 65536**

Is there any way to limit the range of ports to be used by Ehcache (eg say between 40000 and 50000) ?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that were possible. The only reason the range 0-1024 is excluded, is because that requires root permissions on Linux. The rest is the normal range of ports.

Comment: But I have restriction to use only certain range of ports. Is there any way?

Comment: Don't pass a port outside of the range you want to use?

Comment: But cache replication takes port dynamically. so not sure where to limit the ports